# Global Callback from Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, callback

Thanks to an ongoing integration, I'm currently trying to get 2 JS applications running on the same page (one in Angular 2, other in React) to communicate with each other. Currently, all the data sharing happens between the 2 using an object in the window scope of the page (not ideal, but straightforward) and since data is non-critical, it'll make do. This is what that looks like

```
<script>
window.sharedStuff = {oscar_winner: "LALALAND", news: "FAKE"}
</script>

// The angular 2 Application
<my-app>
</my-app>

// React App
<div class="react-app">
</div>
```

However, I'm having issue setting up callbacks from the Angular application which the React application can listen to and perform some action upon. Basically, when a specific event occurs in an Angular component, I want to inform the React application that it has occured. How can I do this? I have access to the window scope from both Angular and react, so ideally, I want to use the window.sharedStuff itself to define a callback which the react application can bind to. But I can't find any documentation on how to go about this (Perhaps because this is a unique/weird situation).

How would I go about this? Help much appreciated!

Comment: You could implement simple Observer pattern and make Angular app broadcast events, and React subscribe to those.

Comment: That's the same thing I said which you disagreed with?   My example is a quick example of how to add an event listener for click events the same concept holds true for the observer pattern.

Comment: @navinpai Check this quick example I set up: http://plnkr.co/edit/NT1eGQUvoKSAnH9ZwgeB?p=info

Comment: @dfsq is there any documentation on broadcasting events to the window scope rather than the root scope of the angular app?

edit: You posted the example just as I sent my reply. This looks perfect! Could you please post that as an answer so I may accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases like yours you can always create mediator or some implementation of Observable pattern. For example quick and simplest one could looks like this:

```
window.observer = {
  listeners: {},

  subscribe (event, callback) {
    this.listeners[event] = this.listeners[event] || []
    this.listeners[event].push(callback)
  },

  broadcast (event, data) {
    if (Array.isArray(this.listeners[event])) {
      this.listeners[event].forEach(callback => callback(data))
    }
  }
}
```

And it could be used by Angular 2 app to push data with `broadcast` method. React app on other hand could subscribe on the same `window.observer` and set it's state:

```
window.observer.subscribe('name.selected', name => {
  this.setState({ name })
})
```

Check the simple demo with Angular 2 and React apps talking like good friends: http://plnkr.co/edit/NT1eGQUvoKSAnH9ZwgeB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Why not add an event listener to the window object and have your React app fire the event which is picked up by Angular and vice versa?

```
window.addEventListener('click', function () { alert('hello world') });
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with DOM events.

Comment: The concept should be the same, setup a custom event and add a listener for it.